# How could I cache all the server requests for the frontend developer use

Tags: frontend, charles-proxy

The request between dev server and front-end is pretty slow.
I'd like to know is there any tool could record requests between the server and the frontend and if there's an occurred request then just use it without firing remote request to the server.

Any idea?